# Linking to controller action using Twig's path() does not automatically find the Entity for the given id, string given

Tags: symfony

I'm migrating from Symfony 3.4.x to 5.4.x. I started with a new Symfony Flex project and copied/moved all the configuration and my bundle over to the new installation.

Everything is working, except the automatic transform when linking to a controller action from a Twig template.

My (simplified) controller action:

```
/**
 * Single view for a site
 *
 * @Route("/Site/Single/{domain}", name="site_single")
 * @param Domains $domain
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function singleAction(Domains $domain, Request $request)
{
    $report = $request->query->has('action') && $request->query->get('action') === 'report';
    $extensionsOnDomain = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Versions::class)
        ->findExtensionsOnDomain($domain->getId());
    ...
}
```

My Twig template that links to this action:

```
{% for domain in domains %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ path('site_single', {'domain': domain.id}) }}">
                {% if domain.domainalias %} {{ domain.domainalias }} {% else %} {{ domain.domainname }} {% endif %}
            </a>
        </td>
    ...
```

The rendering of eveyrthing works well, but when I click the link the id is not converted/transformed to the Domains Entity resulting in the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to My\Bundle\Controller\SiteController::singleAction() must be an instance of My\Bundle\Entity\Domains, string given, called in /var/www/websites//vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php on line 163

I've tried looking for missing bundles or configuration, but cannot find why the auto transform does not work for the Entity.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is unrelated to `twig`... Have a look at [`ParamConverter`](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html)

Comment: @DarkBee thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Was this behavior removed in any version between 3.4 and 5.4? Because in Symfony 3.4 this still worked automagically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big thanks to @DarkBee for pointing me in the right direction.
Apparently this only works when the [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/index.html) is installed.

The conversion is automatically added because the bundle includes the [@ParamConverter](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html)

Update: [Symfony 6.2](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-2-built-in-cache-security-template-and-doctrine-attributes) will add this functionality, anything prior to 6.2 has to have the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle installed

Comment: So you added the Sensio bundle and things started to work?  I ask because the bundle is considered to be abandoned with it's functionality moved to Symfony core.  Unless you are actually using the annotation (which I did not see in your question) then param conversion really should work in a fresh 5.4 app without the bundle.  Just something to keep in mind when moving to 6.x.

Comment: @Cerad it only works when I install the extra bundle. Without it it doesn't work. Are you sure the ParamConverter (or anything similar) should work out of the box? If so could you link to the bundle or package that includes it in Symfony itself?

Comment: [This](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-2-built-in-cache-security-template-and-doctrine-attributes) talks a bit about new core attribute based param converter options.  They were introduced in 6.2 but I was really under the impression that the param converter stuff would work in 5.4 without the sensio bundle.  Looks like I was wrong though I still wonder why the bundle was not installed in the first place.  Oh well.

Comment: I've seen this just now, but it remains a mystery. I've added a todo block to remove the bundle in the future, as it should definitely work in >=6.3